# How to conditionally add or not onClick on a div in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know if it is possible to set `onClick` on a div element in react based on the value of a property in my case `canClick`.

I am aware that I can check this.state directly in `handler` instead I am looking for a solution to be implemented inside `render`.

```js
...
handler(){
}

render() {
  const { canClick} = this.state
  return (
    <div onClick={this.handler}>hello</div>
  )
}
...
```

Answer (score 101):

Put the condition like this:

```
onClick={canClick ? this.handler : undefined }
```

Working Code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
   _click(){
      // it will not print the value
      console.log('yes');
   }

   render(){
      return (
        <div>
          <div onClick={false ? this._click : undefined }>Click</div>
        </div>
      )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: could you add a link reference to "or" I never seen it before in js :) thanks

Comment: hehe, its a english word means any one :)

Comment: when evaluating to `false` I still received the error.  I used `undefined` as in other answer successfully.

Answer (score 82):

You can treat the elements attributes (like onClick) as object properties.
Use the spread operator to only on condition, spread the onClick:

```
<div
  {...(canClick && { onClick: this.handler })}
>
  hello
</div>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, use this people, no point of creating onclick="null" as above answer by Mayank Shukla.

Comment: Great! Mark it as perfect answer

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek `null` may not throw an error but in the prop tree will still show up as `onClick: null` which is not recommended. `undefined` will not show-up on the prop tree. I have updated the top  answer to reflect this. This takes it a step further and completely removes it from prop obj, removing even they key value.

Comment: Perfect, so clean!

Answer (score 23):

```
<div onClick={canClick ? this.handler : undefined} />
```

If you opt for a different falsy value instead of `undefined` in this ternary (i.e. `false` or `null`) React (currently) throws the following warning:

"If you used to conditionally omit it with onClick={condition && value}, pass onClick={condition ? value : undefined} instead."

**Edit 2020-01-05: only `false` throws the above error ([React source code here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/edeea0720791f998b505f2ecdcf866c7e539e7a2/packages/react-dom/src/client/ReactDOMComponent.js#L230)).**

Comment: it's not true because when onclick fired on div, it will call a function but undefined it a function and code will explosion.

Comment: The code won’t explode, I’ve just run this code again and it works fine. The event listener isn’t attached to the DOM node if its value is `undefined`. The JSX above gets converted to an object by `React.createElement`, including its props. Anything with a value of `undefined` is disregarded and not used when creating/updating the actual node in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the source code. Code wil only "explode", meaning give a warning, when you pass `false`. But you'll be fine when passing `null` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this

```
{...(condition ? { onClick: () => {handleClick()}} : {})}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for this, exactly what I was looking for. Didn't need much of an explanation.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can with ternaru operator, which evaluates the left side as boolean and if true it executes the right side or the fallback.

```
<div onClick={() => canClick ? this.handler() : () => false }>hello</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uwzn4n

Answer (score 1):

You can add **Conditional Operator** for this kind of purpose.

```
handler(){
}
render() {
  const { canClick} = this.state
  return (
      <div>
       {
        (canClick) ? 
         (<div onClick={this.handler}>clickble</div>) : 
         (<div>not clickble</div>)
        }
      </div>

  )
}
```

Here is document example for that [reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: Dont do this. See above answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
onClick={(canClick && this.handler) || null}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
handler(){
}    
render() {    
const { canClick} = this.state    
return (
    <div onClick={()=>{canClick&&this.handler()}}>hello</div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a function called `handleClick()` and want to make it available when `current` is bigger than one, been `current` an integer variable, then you can do something like so:

```
onClick={current > 1 ? handleClick : null}
```

Comment: That's a type mismatch. Try this: `onClick={current > 1 ? handleClick : () => null}`. Although `onClick={current > 1 ? handleClick : undefined}` is fine.