# Simplest way to add a click event to react component based on props

Tags: reactjs

So, I have an icon component - For example, a search magnifying glass.  Sometimes I'd like this icon to have a click function - `<icon onClick={} />` which works fine.  Other times I just want to use it for purely visual purposes.

I know I could pass some sort of function boolean prop.  If true, return X, else Y.

The reason I don't want to do this with my icon component is because it's built up of a lot of SVG path information and it seems silly to duplicate all of that for the sake of adding an onClick event.

Is there a tidier, simpler way of doing that?

Here's an example of my code:

**Function with param**

```
export function myFunction(param) {
    // Do something
}
```

**Component 1:**

```
import { myFunction } from "xxx";

const Icon = ({ ...props }) => {
    const {
        myParam,
    } = props;

    return ( <icon></icon> ); // Actually lots of svg stuff going on here...
}
```

*What I'd like to happen sometimes:*

```
return ( <icon onClick={() => myFunction(myParam)}></icon> );
```

*This works, but I'm not sure it's the best, or cleanest way?!*

```
import { myFunction } from "xxx";

const Icon = ({ ...props }) => {
    const {
        myParam,
        clickEvent // true or false
    } = props;

    if (clickEvent ) {
        return ( <icon onClick={() => myFunction(myParam)></icon> );
    } else {
        return ( <icon></icon> );
    }
}
```

**Component 2:**

```
const SomeDiv = ({ ...props }) => {
    const {
        // Props,
    } = props;

    return ( <div><icon myParam="paramStuff" /></div> );

    // Or

    return ( <div><icon myParam="paramStuff clickEvent={true}" /></div> );
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to conditionally add or not onClick on a div in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223852/how-to-conditionally-add-or-not-onclick-on-a-div-in-react)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write it like this as well:

```
const Icon = ({ ...props }) => {
    const {
        myParam,
        clickEvent // true or false
    } = props;
    const onClick = clickEvent  ? () => myFunction(myParam) : undefined;
    return ( <icon onClick={onClick}/> );
}
```

Comment: That's great!  Thanks a lot, really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the prop if it is getting passed and type of prop is `function` and then based on that you can click or remove the click function. Something like below:

```
<icon 
  onClick={() => clickEvent ? myFunction(myAgrs): null } />
```

You can make it more generic and accept function as props you can do something like:

```
const { myFunction } = this.props;
<icon 
  onClick={() => myFunction && typeof myFunction === 'function'? myFunction(myAgrs): null } />
```